# Black/Blank Screen when app is opened

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have successfully implemented Google's SlidingTabLayout and it is working as expected but my view is showing a black screen below it. Like so:

[image]

Here is the my activity main layout folder:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation= "16dp">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="220dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:id = "@+id/stickylist">

 <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipper1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:flipInterval="2000"
    android:inAnimation="@android:anim/fade_in"
    android:outAnimation="@android:anim/fade_out"
    >

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/front"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/str_img1"
    />

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/field"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/str_img2"
    />

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/cafeteria"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/str_img3"
    />
</ViewFlipper>
<se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:divider="@drawable/customdrawershape"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then here is where I implement my PagerAdapter in SlidingTabsBasicFragment:

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs, container, false);
....}
```

tabs.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<xxx.xxx.xxx.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/pager_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="16dp"/>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight ="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is where I call on the fragment in my activity class:

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    SlidingTabsBasicFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsBasicFragment();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

I do have other simultaneous fragments ongoing from the main activity that should be displayed. Is that what is going on? Here is the code for that fragment using a different layout for both what is displayed as well as the frame layout for the fragment container.

```
    manager = getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    EventFragment fragment = new EventFragment();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

The fragment container for the view I am trying to display that is not showing is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the layout to the first fragment which uses a custom adapter for each list view tile integrated in from a different layout.

```
<RelativeLayout

xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:background="@drawable/background">


<TextView
    android:id= "@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/string5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below= "@+id/progressBar"
    android:textColor="#FFD600"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:color="#42A5F5"
    android:indeterminateTint="#42A5F5"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="multiply"/>


<com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.JazzyListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:

Ok now I can get it show the screen by doing the following:

```
 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // Inflate a new layout from our resources
        switch (position){
            case 0:
               view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.eventlistview,
                container, false);


                new Event();
              break;
            case 1:
                view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.twitter,
                        container, false);
                new Twitter();
                 break;
            case 2:
                view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stafflistview,
                        container, false);
               new Staff();
                     break;
            case 3:
                view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.powerschool,
                        container, false);
                new powerschool();
                break;
        }
        // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
        container.addView(view);

        // Return the View
        return view;
    }
```

But eventually the progress bar for the fragment layout I have code for is supposed to go away and a list view is to be displayed. However, it will just show this layout forever even though there is more going on in the background. Any ideas?

This is so limited if all you can do is a single layout. Seriously? This is bad.

Comment: and your fragments layout?

Comment: Which one are you referring to?

Comment: view pager contains fragments right? those fragments need to have layouts ?

Comment: let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: So no one has had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Wild guesses...

in your tabs.xml: your `ViewPager` has a weight of  `android:layout_weight ="1"` and a height of `android:layout_height="0dp"` your slidingtablayout has a height of `wrap_content` and ther father has not `weightsum`.. Change their father's weightsum to 1 and see..

let me know if it helps